# Avoid lines "backwards"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a result file that essentially combines multiple experiments. I want to plot all experiments in one diagram to give an intuition for the distribution of the results. Is there a way to "restart" plotting when the data points move "backwards", instead of actually going "back"?

Here is a simple example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
x  y
0  0
5  5
10  1
0  0
5  2.5
10  1
0  0
5  1
10  1
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    grid=both,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=3cm]

    \addplot table[smooth, mark=none]  {data.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to get rid of the lines at the bottom of the triangle, e.g. the line from (10,1) to (0,0) should be filtered because 10 > 0.

Comment: You could add blank lines in the original data if you want a break.  Otherwise, you will need to extract the data using pgfplotstable and break it into sections.

Comment: Unrelated: `[smooth,mark=none]` is in the wrong place, it should be after `\addplot`, not after `table`. Not that you would want to use `smooth`, but that's another matter.

Comment: What is possible is to construct a filter that marks the **backward point**  as `nan`. This will sacrifice this data point and create a **jump**.

Comment: @John Kormylo: That is a very nice solution. Do you mind creating an answer?

Comment: Adding blank lines?  it's in the manual (page 45).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
x  y
0  0
5  5
10  1

0  0
5  2.5
10  1

0  0
5  1
10  1
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    grid=both,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=3cm]

    \addplot table[smooth, mark=none]  {data.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: DEMO]